# Is it safe to leave "back ground mining" on as long as I want too?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mining, background, 0.11.0.0

I know that the "back ground mining" option with the new 0.11.0.0 version of Monero Core is 'experimental', but is it relatively safe to leave on and not worry about your computer over heating?  Especially if I'm running the GUI on my laptop?  How does it regulate itself?

Comment: anyway you should always monitor your device heating and make sure that it don't pass the limit.
do you have a link for that miner to test it?????

Comment: @MahmoudZowien this is in the official GUI, available at https://getmonero.org/downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, leaving it on in the background should be fine. Background mining limits CPU usage to 40%, so you shouldn't have any trouble with overheating.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_basic/miner.h#L100

```
static constexpr uint8_t  BACKGROUND_MINING_DEFAULT_MINING_TARGET_PERCENTAGE        = 40;
static constexpr uint8_t  BACKGROUND_MINING_MIN_MINING_TARGET_PERCENTAGE            = 5;
static constexpr uint8_t  BACKGROUND_MINING_MAX_MINING_TARGET_PERCENTAGE            = 50;
```

Also FYI, on a laptop it will also check that you're on AC power so it doesn't kill your battery (although you can override that check).